# Using recursion to count nodes in a binary tree, test equality of linked lists, and find extrema of a linked list

Tags: python, recursion, python-3.x, tree, linked-list

I am working with a some small functions to test recursion. I am fairly new to Python and am wondering if there is a cleaner way to get the job done.

```
def count(t,p):

    ''' recursive function when passed a binary tree (it doesn’t matter if it is a 
    binary search tree) and a predicate as arguments; it returns a count of all the 
    values in the tree for which the predicate returns True. '''
    if t == None or t.value == None:
        return 0
    elif p(t.value):
        return 1 + count(t.right, p) + count(t.left, p)
    else:
        return count(t.right, p) + count(t.left, p)



def equal(ll1,ll2):

    ''' recursive function when passed two linked lists; it returns whether or not 
    the linked lists contain exactly the same values in the same order. '''
    if ll1 == None and ll2 == None:
        return True
    if (ll1 != None and ll2 == None) or\
        (ll2 != None and ll1 == None):
        return False
    elif ll1.value == ll2.value:
        return equal(ll1.next, ll2.next)
    else:
        return False


def min_max(ll):

    ''' a recursive when passed a linked list; it returns a 2-tuple containing the 
    minimum value followed by the maximum value. If the linked list is empty, return 
    (None, None) '''
    if ll == None:
        return None, None
    maybe_min, maybe_max  = min_max(ll.next)
    if maybe_min == None or ll.value < maybe_min:
        least = ll.value
    if maybe_min != None and ll.value > maybe_min:
        least = maybe_min
    if maybe_max == None or ll.value >= maybe_max:
        most = ll.value
    if maybe_max != None and ll.value < maybe_max:
        most = maybe_max
    return least, most
```

Comment: Please quit starting titles with "clean code".  The desire for clean code is already implied on this site, so it adds nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to test for [`x is None` rather than `x == None`](//stackoverflow.com/a/16636358/1157100).

---

Avoid using single-letter variable names — they may make sense to you, but not to anyone else.

I don't see any reason why a node should be automatically not counted if its value is `None`.  Shouldn't it be up to the predicate to decide whether nodes with `None` as a value are counted or not?

You can eliminate a case by taking advantage of the fact that `int(False)` is 0 and `int(True)` is 1.

```
def count(tree_node, predicate):
    """Counts the tree_node and its descendants whose value satisfies the predicate."""
    if tree_node is None:
        return 0
    else:
        return int(predicate(tree_node.value)) + \
               count(tree_node.left, predicate) + \
               count(tree_node.right, predicate)
```

---

Stylistically, it would be better to consistently use either one long `if… elif` chain or just `if`s with early `return`s.  I also suggest putting the recursive case at the end of the function.

`(ll1 != None and ll2 == None) or (ll2 != None and ll1 == None)` can be simplified.

```
def equal(ll1, ll2):
    """Recursively checks whether two linked lists contain the same values
    in the same order."""
    if ll1 is None and ll2 is None:
        return True
    if ll1 is None or ll2 is None:
        return False
    if ll1.value != ll2.value:
        return False
    return equal(ll1.next, ll2.next)
```

---

Assuming that the linked list contains no `None` data values, the logic can be simplified.

```
def min_max(ll):
    """Returns a 2-tuple of the minimum and maximum values.
    If ll is empty, returns (None, None)."""
    if ll is None:
        return None, None
    if ll.next is None:
        return ll.value, ll.value
    least, greatest = min_max(ll.next)
    return min(ll.value, least), max(ll.value, greatest)
```

Answer (score 1):

Python not my favorite language (but recursion is).

I would personally move the recursion out of the tests. Thus you do the test for return and other things first. Then the final statement is just a recursive call. This is because a lot work has gone into optimizing tail recursion and you can get significant benifits from it.

So:

```
def count(t,p):

    if t == None or t.value == None:
        return 0

    result = 1 if p(t.value) else 0

    return result + count(t.right, p) + count(t.left, p)
```

and

```
def equal(ll1,ll2):

     if ll1 == None and ll2 == None:
        return True
    if (ll1 != None and ll2 == None) or\
        (ll2 != None and ll1 == None):
        return False
    elif ll1.value != ll2.value:
        return False

    return equal(ll1.next, ll2.next)
```

Comment: @LokiAstari- Thanks. Any input on the min_max function?